# Copying a Wordpress Site to a Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, migration, subdomain

I am copying my site [The Sydney Visitor](http://thesydneyvisitor.com) to the subdomain new.thesydneyvisitor.com. The reason is that i want to change the design while my old site is still active.

What I have done so far:

- Copied all the files to the sub-domain directory using ftp.
- Created a new database
- Exported the old site database and imported it to the new database
- Edited the `wp-config` file (in the subdomain directory) to point to the new database
- Updated the `wp-options` table to reflect the url change
- Run this query to update the URL change in the posts

  ```
  UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid,'http://www.thesydneyvisitor.com','http://www.new.thesydneyvisitor.com');
  ```

The problem:

After doing all these when I try accessing the site using the subdomain url I get the following errors:

```
Warning: require(/home/rapidtem/public_html/new/wp-includes/load.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rapidtem/public_html/new/wp-settings.php on line 21

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/rapidtem/public_html/new/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/rapidtem/public_html/new/wp-settings.php on line 21
```

Kindly assist. I am stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check the following things.

1. Properly configured the sub-domain directory.
2. Copied all the wordpress files to the new directory. (I prefer zip the wordpress folder and upload to the new place to avoid any file loss)
3. Correct database names given in wp-config.php
4. The new directory has the read/write permissions (Check is it a password protected folder or not)

If everything above is fine, then the problem will be in your new database.
Instead of running a query to update the URL change in the posts do the following steps:

1. Goto wp-options table and edit the site_url ( at 1st row), home (around 39th row ) and upload_path ( atround 58th row).

Here is a detailed tutorial [How to move wordpress to a new server or host.](http://blog.triphp.com/how-to/how-to-move-wordpress-to-a-new-server-or-host.html)

There are some plugin available to do these search and replace in database. [Check this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the referenced files exist in those locations?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the Home and Site URL from the Wordpress Database?